# Swift Firebase Refreshing TableView causes cells to repeat

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableview refresh action and when used it cause 2 extra duplicate cells to appear. I have been reading over the code and testing what could cause the refresh to create 2 extra duplicate cells. Not sure about this. When I refresh it will create 2 duplicate extra cells and then the table view spinning wheel will keep on turning and not disappear.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            print("No access")
            fetchPosts()
        //getAllPostsWithoutLocation(refreshing: false, refreshControl: nil)
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Access")
            fetchPostsWithLocation()
            //getAllPosts(refreshing: false, refreshControl: nil)
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services are not enabled")
    }

    // refresh control
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshControlAction(refreshControl:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    self.feedTableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, at: 0)

}


@objc func refreshControlAction(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            print("No access")
            fetchPosts()
        //getAllPostsWithoutLocation(refreshing: true, refreshControl: refreshControl)
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Access")
            fetchPostsWithLocation()
            //getAllPosts(refreshing: true, refreshControl: refreshControl)
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services are not enabled")
    }

}



func fetchPostsWithLocation() {
    Database.database().reference().child("user_profiles").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).child("following").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
            // retrieves all users from database
            databaseRef.child("user_profiles").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (usersSnapshot) in
                let users = usersSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                // retrieve user's following list and append it
                for (_, value) in users {
                    print(value)
                    if let userID = value["uid"] as? String {
                        if userID == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                            print(value)
                            if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String : String] {
                                for (_,user) in followingUsers {
                                    self.following.append(user)
                                }
                            }
                            // append user's id to see own posts
                            //self.following.append(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
                            // retrieve all posts from the database
                            databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (postsSnapshot) in
                                let posts = postsSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                                // retrieve posts of each follower and user
                                for (_, post) in posts {
                                    for (_, postInfo) in post as! [String: AnyObject] {
                                        if let followingID = postInfo["uid"] as? String {
                                            for each in self.following {
                                                if each == followingID {
                                                    guard let uid = postInfo["uid"] as! String! else {return}
                                                    guard let caption = postInfo["caption"] as! String! else {return}
                                                    guard let downloadURL = postInfo["download_url"] as! String! else {return}
                                                    guard let name = postInfo["businessName"] as! String! else {return}
                                                    guard let timestamp = postInfo["timestamp"] as! Double! else {return}
                                                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)
                                                    guard let address = postInfo["businessStreet"] as! String! else {return}
                                                    guard let state = postInfo["businessCity"] as! String! else {return}
                                                    guard let postID = postInfo["postID"] as! String! else {return}

                                                    let lat = Double(postInfo["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                                                    let long = Double(postInfo["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                                                    let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                                                    let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                                                    let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                                                    let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                                                    let distanceInMeters: Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                                                    let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
                                                    let distanceLabelText = String(format: "%.2f miles away", distanceInMiles)

                                                    self.feeds.append(Post(uid: uid, caption: caption, downloadURL: downloadURL, name: name, date: date, address: address, state: state, distance: distanceLabelText, postID: postID))
                                                }
                                                self.feeds.sort {$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending}
                                                //self.feeds.sort {$0.distance.compare($1.distance) == .orderedAscending}

                                                self.feedTableView.reloadData()
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                            }) { (error) in
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("Not following anyone")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Now that I am checking it thoroughly I believe its because my calls need to be like this: "fetchPosts(refreshing: false, refreshControl: nil)" but then a error is thrown saying "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: Looks like you just continue to append data to your data source array.  Every time you refresh you are not purging the data and repopulating but simply appending all data onto it again..

Comment: rMickeyD how would you recommend fixing this problem?